# Azure Apim Bearer token

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

Hi guys im following the next tutorial from azure:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/subscription/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs [Azure create or update suscriptions]

I already made it work,but i dont know from where comes from the Bearer token that the example uses

Can anybody explain to me how i can get that bearer token? actually im planning to use this to create api keys from the back end but i dont exactly know from where i can request that bearer token.

I know it says "Azure Active Directory OAuth2 Flow" in the part of security but can anyone explain to me how that works?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow have you seen this?

Answer (score 1):

you can get the bearer token by following commands in ***postman***:

`post  https://login.microsoftonline.com/**{tenantid}**/oauth2/token`

From your application you can get the tenant id and client id
***Azure portal ->Azure active directory ->your app->overview***
[image]

***client secret:***
[image]

[image]

When you send the command you can get the ***bearer token.***

[image]

***Reference:***
[Azure REST API: Create Bearer Token - cloudopszone.com](https://cloudopszone.com/azure-rest-api-create-bearer-token/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20the%20Azure%20Active%20Directory%20token%20we,we%20have%20been%20created%20on%20the%20previous%20step)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can generate the Bearer token/access token using cloud shell from the portal by following the below steps

1. Sign-in to the Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com)
2. Open cloud shell, select `Power Shell`
3. If you have multiple subscription, using [set-Azcontext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/set-azcontext?view=azps-8.1.0) cmdlet set a particular subscription as context to perform operation on that subscription.
4. Run the cmdlet `Get-AzAccessToken` this will give you the access token.

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]